# Asp.net MVC debugging on IIS6

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've setup IIS6 to work with MVC, added a new virtual web site, entry in etc/hosts and everything works except when I try to start project from Visual Studio.

I've changed project settings to Local IIS server to url http://myproject and when I try to run project I get

> Unable to start debugging on the web server. An authentication error occurred communicating with the web server.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a lot of problems with IIS6 as well.  I basically deleted my IIS application, reset the asax back and used Cassini.

Then at the end of each [sprint] I setup IIS6 application in the test environment for the testers.

Comment: Agreed. I think that I'll do the same. Or move my development environment to W2K8/IIS7 - maybe I'll have more luck there.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether "Integrated security" option is checked in the website properties, and your account should have sufficient privileges.

Comment: Yes, it is enabled. I am running VS as Administrator